# Small white egg-like sacs with orchid

Tags: pests, orchids

I’ve just noticed small white egg-like sacs on the bark of the branch that I use to grow my tongue orchid *Dockrillia linguiformis*.

In fact the sacs are not solid white but appear to be translucent.

The timber substrate I use is Australian swamp oak *Casuarina glauca*.

It may be circumstance, but I noticed a part of the older length of orchid had been pried away from the bark to which it was fixed. Maybe something laid these “eggs”, or maybe something was trying to eat these “eggs” and either way knocked the section of orchid.

Photos are included below...

[image: small white egg-like sacs - close]

[image: small white egg-like sacs - closer]

Comment: Are they free? Or attached? Could they be a fungus?

Comment: Good questions... yes, the sacs appear to be attached to, but not growing from the bark or the sphagnum moss or the orchid. Yes they could be a fungus, but I know very little about that topic.

Comment: They look  just like slug eggs, but I'm in the UK, you could have other creatures that lay similar eggs

Comment: @Bamboo thats it... I’d never seen slug eggs before or known anything about their lifecycle! (Despite that I’ve been picking them off my leafy plants for weeks.)

Comment: I'd be using slug pellets - sparingly, but using them nonetheless. There'll be adults about somewhere...